# Promise using ".catch()" even though there's no rejection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm only starting to learn about mongoose. This code runs successfully and pushes the document to MongoDB the first time I submit it. But when I try to create another post it fails.

```
//Post.js file
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let Post = function(data, user) {
    this.data = data
    this.username = user
    this.errors = []
}

Post.prototype.validate = function() {
    if (this.data.text == "") {this.errors.push("Cannot be left blank")}
}

Post.prototype.create = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.validate()
        if (!this.errors.length) {
            const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                body: String,
                author: String,
            })
            const PostModel = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
            const post = new PostModel({
                body: this.data,
                author: this.username
            })
            post.save(() => {
                resolve()
            })
        } else {
            console.log("Failed")
        }
    })
}

module.exports = Post

//postController.js file

const Post = require("../models/Post")

exports.create = function(req, res) {
    let post = new Post(req.body.text, req.session.user.username)
    post.create().then(() => {
        res.send("Post created")
    }).catch(() => {
        res.send("Failed")
    })
}
```

So yeah, as stated earlier, the first time you submit a post everything runs successfully, but after the second post I'm guessing some form of an error occurs and ".catch()" gets called in the postController file even though the promise does not contain a "reject()".

Comment: The error will be passed to the `catch` callback. Try logging it.

Comment: A promise can also be rejected if an error is [thrown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Comment: I figured it out, what was happening was that I was redefining the model and schema every time I submitted the form. Doing this, will cause mongoose to throw an error.

Comment: @JustinChristopherDomingo If you have found the solution you can answer yourself and tick the answer as valid.